# I used UICollectionViewFlowLayout category and my app crash sometimes with PhotosUI

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I don't use `PhotosUI framework` in any place of my app .Don't know why I got crash report from PhotosUI .

Here is crash report from Crashlytics .

```
      0 CoreFoundation   __exceptionPreprocess + 130
      1 libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw + 38
      2 CoreFoundation   -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202
      3 CoreFoundation   ___forwarding___ + 706
      4 CoreFoundation   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
      5 MyApp    UICollectionViewFlowLayout+NoFade.m line 42
         -[UICollectionViewFlowLayout(NoFade)noFadeFinalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:]

 6 PhotosUI -[PUSectionedGridLayout finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:]


   -[PUSectionedGridLayout noFadeFinalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d56160
```

It crashed because my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout+NoFade`  tried to call `noFadeFinalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath`
which is not available PUSectionedGridLayout

But I didn't use PUSectionedGridLayout in any of my code.  Is it happen when users select to pick photo from album or something ?  I am not able to reproduct this crashes.  Any solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PUSectionedGridLayout looks to be part of the photos UI internals so it would not be a surprise that it is in your call stack if you were using the photos UI.

https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/PhotosUI.framework/PUSectionedGridLayout.h

However, since you say you are not, at least not directly, the questions is could it be coming in indirectly via either a third party library or an image picker flow?

Comment: I think it comes up from imagePicker. But the problem is I can't reproduce the same crash even if I use imagePicker ,the app won't crash.